# OpenVPN intercepts local Samba traffic between Laptop and PC over WiFi (Windows)

Tags: routing, openvpn, samba

I have a weird problem with OpenVPN - it seems it somehow intercepts 'local' traffic.

I have PC + Notebook, both are in parallel connected to each other via:

- WiFi - network 192.168.0.x
- OpenVPN over same WiFi - network 192.168.7.x
- (optionally) via LAN, direct ethernet cable - network 192.168.254.x

When I try to copy files from one to another on Windows - from `\\192.168.0.x\share` to `\\192.168.0.y\share` I get speed of around 5MB/s. This is extremely low and after lengthy experiments trying to find the reason, I've noticed that when I shut down OpenVPN, speed restores to normal (`~25MB/s` over WiFi and `~100MB/s` over direct LAN).

Any ideas what is happening there? How to fix the speed?

...

Using hints on another site, I've captured the trafic using Wireshark. Out of it I see that SMB2 session initially connects on expected interfaces (192.168.0.160 -> 192.168.0.197), but then at some point of time without noticable reason reconnects on IPs from OpenVPN subnet (192.168.7.160 -> 192.168.7.60). The strange thing is that SMB reconnect happened aproximatelly 5 minutes after I've restarted OpenVPN connection, not immediattely.

[image: Wireshark capture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [SMB Multichannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn610980(v=ws.11)). It thinks that the VPN adapter (which probably claims to be 10G) is faster than the WLAN adapter. (If you look at the details of the Ioctl call, you'll see the client querying the server's network interface details.) Try disabling multichannel using either of:

- on server, `Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableMultiChannel $false`;
- on client, `Set-SmbClientConfiguration -EnableMultiChannel $false`.

Comment: Yes, it appears the reason is exactly 'that' - already noticed while digging deeper in Wireshark and waiting for the answer that Ioctrl response contained 2 intefaces '1.0 GBits/s, IPv4: 192.168.7.60 + 866.0 MBits/s, IPv4: 192.168.0.197' and OpenVPN channel is claimed to be 'faster'. May be you know how to change the declared link speed? Google did not help me with that so far :( ... Disabling 'multichannel' indeed helps already.